# jQuery .on() method not executing jQuery functions on elements

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm trying to create a dynamic list of buttons that will react to the user.  Here's the code:

```
$('#left').on("mouseenter", 'div', function() {
    dispEvent($(this).hasClass('button');
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');
});

$('#left').on("mouseleave", 'div', function(event) {
    dispEvent($(event.target).hasClass('button');
    $(this).removeClass('highligted');
});

$('#left').on('click', 'div', function(event) {
    dispEvent(event.target == this);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

The '#left' id is the static container (a button panel) of the divs in question.  dispEvent is a helper function that displays information.  I know that the function is executing because my display is updating when the event should fire.
I also know that it is finding an html element, that that element has the correct class, and the event target and the 'this' I'm referencing are the same (as the display prints 'true'), but for some reason I can't add the class within the .on() method.
I added the class via $([selector]).hover() to a statically created button to make sure that the class name was right and .addClass() worked correctly (it did function as expected).

Also, since $(this).hasClass('button') is returning true and the testing .remove() is removing the elements, I know that it recognizes the element and can wrap it into a jQuery object and perform functions on it.

To recap.  The addClass() function and highlight class work with hover over a static object, the .on() is recognizing the event and entering its code, jQuery recognizes the object as an html element and can perform at least some functions on it, but it can't add the class within .on(). (When I have the .on() function even the static button will not add the highlight class).

Sorry for the wordiness of the question, but I wanted to be thorough.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: this is very wordy. please post more of your code and possibly a jsfiddle. thanks.

Comment: If I didn't clarify, how can I get addClass to work?

Comment: Always debug js using your console, obvious syntax errors

Comment: sad my close vote limit reached...

Comment: @TJ You are devil... :)  *edit:* oops sorry, i read downvote

Comment: @A.Wolff Yep didn't downvote... both close votes and close vote reviews reached their limit.. :/ I am fighting the `11k` review queue  :)

Comment: Sorry, here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lmcsvudk/

Comment: @TJ To what errors do you refer?  Admittedly, I'm new to this syntax, but I'm following the guide that I learned html/css/js/jquery.

Comment: @LushKitch I didn't refer to any errors 0__0 ... as per the existing answer, you've a simple typo or syntax error in your code... such questions can be closed mentioning the same reason, So that multiple users won't post answers one after another pointing to same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is extremely simple. you misspelled `highlighted`

```
.highligted {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
    cursor: pointer;
}

//Event Handlers
$('#left').on("mouseenter", 'div', function() {
dispEvent($(this).hasClass('button'));
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');
});

$('#left').on("mouseleave", 'div', function(event) {
dispEvent($(event.target).hasClass('button'));
    $(this).removeClass('highligted');
});
```

Comment: Sweet lord.  I swear I checked that like five times and copy-pasted the name.  Well, thank you... I feel like a real idiot now.  I appreciate you taking the time to look that over.  I'll look over my version history to see what happened.

Comment: you might want to use css `:hover` and `:active` in place of `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` and `click`

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `:active`.  But it looks a lot simpler to deal with, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in the code, so it won't run at all:

```
dispEvent($(this).hasClass('button');
```

should be:

```
dispEvent($(this).hasClass('button'));
```

And the same for the second `dispEvent` call.

If you open up the error console in the browsers, there should be a syntax error message.

Comment: That was actually a transfer error.  The code is correct in my file and the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lmcsvudk/